# WSO2 - Configuring JPA

Tags: jpa, deployment, wso2

We developed an app using JPA (via Hibernate).
And in WSO2 we expose a service in soap that uses the models defined in our app.
The persistence is configured through a persistence.xml file.
The way we deployed it is :

.car contains .aar (our app that contains a jar with our models)

inside the .jar in META-INF I can see the persistence file, but when calling the service it complaines about the fact that it can't find the persistence.
I tried to put the persistence file at the .aar level too but no success.

Do I need to put the persistence file at a particular place ?

Thanks !

Comment: did you find a way/example of use JPA in WSO2? I am facing the same problem

Comment: yes I did let me know if still need the information I'll try to provide you example

Comment: great, yes please